# Is there any way to copy pagefile.sys or swapfile.sys while they are in use (without rebooting)?

Tags: windows

"Normal" copying doesn't work because the files are in use and system-protected (and apparently VSS is also ineffective), so I'm unsure as to how to proceed.

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. [Edit] the question if there is.

Comment: I use Linux, so can only answer cinceptually.  Its possible, but not without special steps. The issue is that those files will likely become inconsistent and tjus corrupt during copy.  A common way to do this would be to use a filesystem that allows snapshotting, then back up off the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it won't be quite so easy. Out of curiosity, I mounted an image made by [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) using Windows [Volume Shadow Copy Service (VSS)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/volume-shadow-copy-service) and there *are* files named *hiberfile.sys*, *pagefile.sys*, and *swapfile.sys*. However, when examined in [HxD Hex Editor](https://mh-nexus.de/en/), all three files contained only 0x00 (null) characters.

[image: System Files]

This does not *prove* that VSS does not copy the data; it might be that the data is set to nulls  by Reflect, perhaps for security purposes. However, what seemed like a straight-forward path to copy those files failed.

However, it may be possible to [view the data in RAM](https://andreafortuna.org/2019/05/15/how-to-read-windows-hibernation-file-hiberfil-sys-to-extract-forensic-data/) using a tool such as [FTK Imager](https://www.exterro.com/ftk-imager). *Caveat:* I've not tried that forensic tool and cannot vouch for it's safety or efficacy.

Comment: There is no reason VSS would attempt to keep shadow copies of the page file, hibernation file, or the swapfile since they would be created dynamically.  Bottom Line: Windows does not attempt to keep shadow files of system files.  While an individual file does not change often, there are enough system files that do change with cumulative updates, that it would be a horrible idea to NOT blacklist those files in shadow volume.  If Windows attempt to keep previous versions of system files, your shadow volume, would only contain system files.